# List compiled java class's members

Tags: java, .class-file

I have a compiled java class file :

```
HelloWorld.class
```

Is there a command-line command I can use to list all members of the class?

Comment: See if `javap` is useful for your needs.

Comment: Similar question asked here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923799/tool-to-check-package-name-and-class-name-of-the-class-within-a-class-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called javap.

You may have to set a classpath (much the same way you would with the java command) to get javap to find your class, depending on whether it is in a package (and should be in a corresponding subdirectory).

The general syntax is

```
javap HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [javap](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Using_javap.html).  It ships with the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Try `javap -private HelloWorld`.

For more info, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html